# Jerarquia de operaciones Calculadora en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema , realice una calculadora, pero ahora no logro equilibrar la jerarquía de operaciones, por ejemplo si hago la siguiente operacion:

1+1*2
Tendría que ser el resultado = 3
Pero literalmente esta realizando las primeras operaciones, primero la suma y luego la multiplicación
anexo parte del código y adjunto el proyecto

```
String resultado;
        resultado = txtpantalla.getText();
        double tam = resultado.length();
        String A[] = new String[100];
        String resultados[] = new String[100];
        int pos = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        String aux = "";
        resultados[0] = "+";
        //Para sumar
        if (signo.equals("+")) {
            int index_operacion = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
                if (resultado.charAt(i) == '+' || resultado.charAt(i) == '-' || resultado.charAt(i) == '*' || resultado.charAt(i) == '/') {
                    A[pos] = aux;
                    resultados[index_operacion] = String.valueOf(resultado.charAt(i));
                    pos++;
                    index_operacion++;
                    aux = "";
                } else {
                    aux = aux + resultado.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            A[pos] = aux;
            pos++;

            for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
                //Determina la operación a realizar.         
                if (resultados[i].equals("+")) {
                    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
                } else if (resultados[i].equals("-")) {
                    sum = sum - Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
                } else if (resultados[i].equals("*")) {
                    sum = sum * Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
                } else if (resultados[i].equals("/")) {
                    sum = sum / Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ejili5p8oot9xq/Calculadora.rar?dl=0

Comment: Para resolver correctamente una operación aritmética, usualmente se utiliza un _árbol de expresiones_ (expression tree en Inglés). Si construyes correctamente tu árbol de expresiones (para lo cual se usa una pila), resolver la operación es un paso trivial. Te dejo un enlace a un artículo (en inglés) que habla del tema. [Simple arithmetic expression Evaluator](http://codinghelmet.com/exercises/expression-evaluator) Y este otro: [Expression Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-tree/).

Comment: Deberías convertir tu expresión a una expresión posfija utilizando pilas. En youTube hay varios videos para hacer eso. Podrías buscar como Evaluador de Funciones en java. Ahí también muestran la jerarquía de las expresiones.

Answer (score -1):

Si puedes has una depuración para ver donde se esta quedando estancado el código, por lo que veo cada iteracion esta haciendo verdadero el `if` de esta sección.

```
if (resultados[i].equals("+")) {
                    sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(A[i]);
```

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta, en realidad no se estanca mi codigo, lo que yo quisiera saber, es como puedo "equilibrar" o hacer que mi calculadora, respete la jerarquia de operaciones.